# Organize code structure NodeJS to make large enterprises application

Tags: .net, node.js, web

It is damn proved that Node JS is much faster and effective way to develop web application with a bright future, but the challenges are :

- Can we manage or make well structure code like in .net development .
- Can we make layered architecture and use different software pattern
  so that we   can easily test and modularize and make clean code ?
- Can we achieve same productivity within less time as in .Net ?

Which tools or plugins available that can provide effective way to achieve these type of goals?

Comment: These questions mostly call for opinions which is off-topic here on stack overflow.